# Percentage data from .csv to excel

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, openpyxl

I read some data under percentage form (11.00%) from a .csv file.
I copy them into an excel file and i want to represent them in a chart.
The problem is, when i copy them into excel, data is automatically converted to string type and i cannot represent them in the chart correctly.
I tried few methods but nothing successfully.

```
f = open("any.csv")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("any.xlsx")
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=0):
        for i in reader:
           ws.append(i[2:]) code here
```

I tried using:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=0): 
   for i in reader: 
      ws.append(float(i[2:]))
```

and i recieve this error:
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

I have tried using:

```
for i in reader:
       i[2:] = [float(x) for x in i[2:]]
       ws.append(i)
```

and i got this eror:
ValueError: invalid literal for float()11.1%

I use the i[2:] because first first and second column contain some text that dont need to be converted

Comment: All you need to do is a write a function that converts `11.1%` to the equivalent numerical value. This could be `11.1` or `0.111` depending on your use case. In Excel you'll want to do the latter and assign a number format.

Comment: hello. i saw that openpyxl allows working with styles and have a number_format = 'General'  attribute which im trying to change it to percentage.

Comment: It is possible to change the cell type after i append the string data and convert it like that?

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=0):
        for i in reader:
           ws.append(float(i[2:-1])) code here
```

Float the value before you append it

Comment: Hello Joel, 
Thanks for answer.
I already tried that and im getting this error:

Comment: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Comment: And if i try another way:
for i in reader:
       i[2:] = [float(x) for x in i[2:]]
       ws.append(i)

Comment: i got this eror: ValueError: invalid literal for float()11.1%

Comment: I changed answer.  You need to lop off the '%' at the end of the string

Comment: Next time, show the actual data you are getting the error on.  That will help answer more quickly

Comment: my i  look like this:

Comment: (Bytes)Sys CPU% Sum    11.10%   11.10%  11.00% 11.00%

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.
Before i append the data into excel i use this:

```
wb.guess_types = True
```

which apparently write the date as percentage as i need

Comment: You can also use it as an input argument in the load_workbook method. `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("any.xlsx", guess_types=True)`